# Add text to a label which already has a text C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Well I'd like to add a string to a Label which already has a text. It means that I want to append a text and not to overwrite the existing text.

```
label2.Content = string.Join("\n", customer);
```

I used `string.Join` but this does not work.

Comment: If its C# then you just add more text to it like ```label2.Text = label2.Text + "more text";```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `customer` is a `string`, you can concat the strings like that:

```
label2.Content = label2.Content + /*" " + */ customer;
```

Or simply:

```
label2.Content += customer;
```

If not a string:

```
label2.Content = customer.ToString();
```

If you want to append as a new line:

```
label2.Content += Environment.NewLine + customer;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
label2.Content += "whatever"
```

Answer (score 0):

What string.Join does is take an array of strings, and a separator, and returns a new string that joins all the elements by adding the separator:

e.g:

```
string[] customers = new string[] { "Customer A", "Customer B", "Customer C" };
string joinedString = string.Join("\n", customers);
//Output:
Customer A
Customer B
Custoemr C
```

What I think you want is to append some string joined by newlines, to an existing label.

For that you'll need to append this joinedString to the existing content of the label as

```
label2.Content += joinedString;
```

[Image: WPF Joined String Label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHzuB.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think this will solve your problem, I am thinking you have a customer class such as below

```
   public class Customer {          
      public string FirstName {get; set;}
      public string LastName {get; set;}
      public string Description {get; set;}
   }
```

and again thinking you want to use your customer object as a string. So you should override `ToString()` method for your object.

Firstly override to string in your class like below:

```
   public class Customer {          
      public string FirstName {get; set;}
      public string LastName {get; set;}
      public string Description {get; set;}

      //overriding
      public override string ToString()
      {
        return FirstName + " " + LastName + ", Desc: " + Description;
      }
   }
```

And now, you can use your `customer` object as a `String` easily,

```
label2.Content += customer.ToString();
```